# x-editable inserts itself breaking table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, x-editable

I have a table with data I present to the user, the old `<table><tr>...` type of table.

To allow the user to edit I use x-editable, but the x-editable div inserts itself after the editable `<td>`s, breaking the flow of the table.

Is there any way to make x-editable just appear there without being inserted between 2 divs?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this? If so please post it.

Comment: No, sorry, I just took out x-editable and coded my own solution.